# Can connect to FTP within local network, but not remotely

Tags: ftp, remote-access

Can't figure this one out.  I've set up FTP with a filezilla server on my windows 7 machine at home.  If I'm within the local network and connect with the LAN 192.168.x.x IP address, it succeeds, but if I attempt to connect to the WAN ip with the port forwarded it fails.

I thought my ISP might be blocking port 21 so this is all done with a random port I chose (port 10622).  The port is reported as open by `www.yougotsignal.com/tools/open-ports`.

Things I've tried on the windows 7 machine:

- Disabling firewall at the domain, home and public levels
- Added additional rules allowing port 10622 to ingoing and outgoing (just in case)
- Checked all settings for "exclude this IP" related settings (there are none)

I have RDP working correctly remotely with the port forwarded, so I don't think it's an issue with my router (which is a dd-wrt flashed cisco router).  I am also successfully forwarding another random port for torrents.

Any suggestions are appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The ftp server is set in Active or passive mode ?

Comment: Passive, although I've tried both.

Comment: `netstat -na`, pls. And check port-forward rules with any smart TCP-listener